# No genera el refresh_token en txt python-O365

Tags: python, microsoft-office

Me encuentro utilizando la librería o365 de python y cuando genero el txt por medio de account.con.request_token(result_url) no me genera el refresh.token simplemente me genera el access_token, este es mi código

```
from O365 import Account

scopes_graph = protocols.get_scopes_for('message_send')
credential = ('client_id', 'client_secret')

account = Account(credentials=credential, scopes=scopes_graph)
account.con.get_authorization_url()
result_url = input('Paste the result url here...')
#'aqui crea el txt pero no genera el 
account.con.request_token(result_url) 
m = account.new_message() 
m.to.add('examples@example.com')
m.subject = 'Testing!'
m.body = "George Best quote: I've stopped drinking, but only while I'm asleep."
m.send()
```

necesito el "refresh_token":"...." gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en la forma en que se valida la URL de verificación la solución es la siguiente:

En vez de utilizar esto

```
account = Account(credentials=credential, scopes=scopes_graph)
account.con.get_authorization_url()
result_url = input('Paste the result url here...')
#'aqui crea el txt pero no genera el 
account.con.request_token(result_url)
```

Utilizar esto

```
account = Account(credentials=credential, scopes=scopes_graph)
account.authenticate(scopes=['basic', 'message_all'])
```

Gracias :)